# Questions about retrieving/refreshing data using Volley (and SimpleXML) on Android

Tags: android, android-volley, simple-framework, rx-android

All the data my Android app displays is taken from a XML file. I'm using Volley to retrieve the data and SimpleXML to map the XML data to objects using a Volley custom Request: [`SimpleXmlRequest`](https://gist.github.com/itsalif/6149365).

Every time I refresh the content, it reads the whole XML file and creates every single object again and I have the feeling that this is not the best way to do it, cause this file can be quite large. So I have a few questions about that:

1. Is there a way to "***subscribe***" to the XML file to retrieve only the
   **new** *items* added on it, avoiding to read the whole file every time? I know Volley can cache but doesn't help so much here.
2. Would it be possible to make a SimpleXml**Array**Request using
       SimpleXML framework? Would it help? Cause I really don't want to
       parse the file by myself...
3. If not, would it worth to **switch from XML to Json** so I could use
       `JsonArrayRequest` or would I have to read the whole file and refresh
       every single item anyway? I've never used it before.
4. Many items from the source file are displayed as a list using
       `RecyclerView` but, again, when I refresh, I have to **remove the items
       it had before and add them all again** as I'm getting all the items at
       once and consequently can't use
       `RecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I've been reading a lot, even until finding out the RxJava and RxAndroid which seems perfect but it looks like too hard to integrate Volley and SimpleXML on it... so I hope you can help me :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I always work with Json apart from being very light, with libraries like GSON its fun to work with.

To get only new new data, my practice is to include two fields in the database tables, 1 for isDeleted (boolean) and 1 for lastModified (long epoc time).

The isDeleted field applies only if the data is accessed by multiple users.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read it and answer but it doesn't help too much to clarify my questions. By the way, I don't use any database.

Comment: hi np..so you manually refresh the data? because data is usually stored in a databse